# Cannot ping to my router

Tags: networking, server

This is my first time here and I am having trouble to ping to my router from Ubuntu 14.04.

I have usb N300 WiFi USB Adapter.

This is the result of `route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         -.-.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.-.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

and the result of `ifconfig`:

```
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:192602563 (192.6 MB)  TX bytes:12965403 (12.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1614347 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1614347 (1.6 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:ef:09:09:eb:8e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.136  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdbe:c617:7981:0:deef:9ff:fe09:eb8e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::deef:9ff:fe09:eb8e/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fdbe:c617:7981:0:355b:6ffe:1462:6775/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2105576 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:423233 (423.2 KB)
```

When I `ping` to the router it tells me that:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=16 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.136 icmp_seq=17 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Salem. What happen if you: 'ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.1'?

Comment: It seems that your router is getting the ping, because your computer at 192.168.1.136 is blocking the router from accessing it. Do you have any firewalls setup?

Comment: binghamton@rtes3:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:"RTES"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: C0:56:27:0E:96:40   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:85/100  Signal level:-41 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1463  Invalid misc:3824192   Missed beacon:0

Comment: How to check the firewalls ?

Comment: Try pinging another host on the network, to rule out if the problem is with the router not responding, or connectivity from your machine.

Comment: "excessive retries:1463 Invalid misc:3824192" I think shall be a driver (module) problem, or maybe you live next to a "radio station" ;-). First, try to connect using 802.11g protocol, then turn off criptography (on your WIFI HOME ROUTER, select "802.11g ONLY" on wifi mode, security mode "NONE"). That way we test if the problem is the protocol 802.11n not correctly managed. Second: use 'lsusb' to find the USB device ID, to better know the wifi USB are you using.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot ping your router ***but connected to it***, the issue is more on the router than the firewalls on your machine. Normally firewall would not block the sending machine from sending out the packets.

Some routers have firewall features called **Block Ping from WAN**. Check your router.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi jarvis, tx to the reply, but salem is on the LAN, block ping from wan block ping from internet, not from him pc